# how can I pass the data from one component to another?

Tags: angular, api, ngfor

I'm trying to pass data from a parent component to a child component. The movie search component uses a service function to gather data, then processes the data so that it's just title and id information. I want to pass it to the details component so that I can make it viewable/clickable. I am getting these bullet points instead of the actual data.

[image]

Below is the component that performs the search and processes the results into an object, as seen in the console log of the screenshot above.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MovieResult } from '../movie-result';
import { MovieQueryService } from '../services/movie-query.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-search',
  templateUrl: './movie-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-search.component.css']
})
export class MovieSearchComponent {
  movies: any = [];
  

  constructor(private queryService: MovieQueryService){}

  search(query: string)
  {
    this.queryService.getData(query).subscribe((movies:any) => {
      this.processResults(movies.results) })
  }

  processResults(movies: any)
  {

  
    movies.forEach((element: any) => {
      this.movies.push([element.title, element.id])
      console.log(this.movies)});
 
  }
  

  ngOnInIt() : void
  {

  }
}
```

Below are the app component HTML files
movie-search.component.html

```
  <div id="search-component">
    <label for="search-box">Movie Search</label>
    <input  #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup.enter)="search(searchBox.value)" />

   
</div>

<app-movie-details [data]="movies"></app-movie-details>
```

movie-search.component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let data of data">
    <p>{{data.title}}</p>
    <p>{{data.id}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a service that isn't provided in the root. You then provide it in the parent component, as it will then be injectable within its child components.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  public test = { a: 1 };
}
```

Here we provide the service in the `@Component`'s `providers`. Everytime an instance of this component is created an instance of the service will be created as well and injectable within the children.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  providers: [SharedService],
  template: `
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private readonly shared: SharedService) {
    shared.test.a = 123;
  }
}
```

Since this component is created within the parent, it will inherit the service that was created in the parent.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '{{shared.test.a}}'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(protected readonly shared: SharedService){}
}
```